# Where I can find list of API Management logging fields

Tags: azure-api-management

I configured APIM logger to EventHub using article 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs
In the example some of the fields are given viz.
`DateTime.UtcNow, context.Deployment.ServiceName, context.RequestId, context.Request.IpAddress`
I want to configure more like who is referrer, result, time etc. 
Where I can find complete list of the fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valid types allowed in policy expressions are listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions.